# Fetching with JoinQueryOver: Get greatgrandchildren, know father

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

Object Structure:
A house has many rooms.
A room has many tables.
A table has many vases (on it).

House > Rooms > Tables > Vases.

I'd like to use JoinQueryOver to select all tables with vases that are red - in a particular house.

I thought to do this:

```
var v = session.QueryOver<House>()
    .Where(x => x.ID == HouseID)
        .JoinQueryOver<Room>(x => x.Rooms)
            .JoinQueryOver<Table>(x => x.Tables)
                .JoinQueryOver<Vase>(x => x.Vases)
                    .Where(x => x.Color == "Red")
    .SingleOrDefault<House>();
```

This was an approach I tried (of the many that failed). I don't really want the House and Room info.

Ultimately, I'm looking for a List of Tables (in a particular house), with their collections of Vases (that are red) fetched.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit**

Something like this would be nice:

```
var v = session.QueryOver<Table>()
        .Where(x => x.Room.House.ID == HouseID) // this Where won't work.
            .JoinQueryOver<Vase>(x => x.Vases)
                .Where(x => x.Color == "Red")
        .List().ToList();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var v = session.QueryOver<Table>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Room, () => room)
    .Where(() => room.House.ID == HouseID)
    .JoinQueryOver<Vase>(x => x.Vases)
        .Where(x => x.Color == "Red")
    .List();
```

Comment: Thanks Firo... this was it. Sorry for the delay.